# When using Next.JS 13 with Google's OAuth, I receive "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch"

Tags: next.js, google-oauth

I am using [Next.JS 13's App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app), with the authentication library [next-auth.js](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#in-app-router) attached to the router.

I have configured Google's OAuth settings as shown [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3KQO.png) - this configuration works perfectly for me when using localhost.

However, when I use a VPS and a real domain, I receive the error `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch` even with the URL parameter `redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google`

I tried to change the URI to localhost as stated but it's absolutely wrong because it's not in localhost anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i can fix this.

if anyone got:

- Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
- redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google

in **production mode**, its because you need to specify this value in your .env file:

- NEXTAUTH_URL=https://yourdomain.com

[you can read it here](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#nextauth_url)